# Functional inequality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $u = u(t,x)$ and
$$
\dot{W}(t) \leq -\left(\frac{\sigma \omega \pi^2}{4L^2} + g\right)\int_0^L u^2 dx - \sigma(1-\omega) \int_0^L u_x^2 dx - aμ \int_0^L u^2_t dx 
$$
$$
-σ^{-1}c^2Q\int_0^L (u_t - σu_{xx}+gu)^2dx + σ^{-1}c^2Q(1 + c^{-2}σ(g-μ))\int_0^L u_t(u_t -σu_{xx} + gu)dx
$$
$$
+ (1 + σ^{-1}c^2Qg) \int_0^L u(u_t -σu_{xx} + gu)dx 
$$

where $\sigma,\mu,a, L, c, Q$ are positive, $g \in \mathbb{R}$, $\omega \in (0,1)$ and

$$
W(t) = \frac12\int_0^Lu^2dx + \frac{Q}{2}\int_0^L(u_t - \sigma u_{xx} + gu)^2dx+\frac{a}{2}\int_0^Lu_t^2 + \frac{ac^2}{2}\int_0^Lu_x^2dx
$$

It has to be shown that there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\dot{W}(t) \leq -\varepsilon W(t)$.

### Attempt:

$$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\sigma\omega\pi^2}{4L^2} + g & 0 & -\frac{\sigma + c^2Qg}{2\sigma} \\
    0 & a\mu & -\frac{Q}{2}\left(\frac{c^2}\sigma + g - \mu \right) \\
    -\frac{\sigma + c^2Qg}{2\sigma} & -\frac{Q}{2}\left(\frac{c^2}\sigma + g - \mu \right)& \frac{c^2Q}{\sigma}
  \end{bmatrix}
\
$$

is the matrix of the quadratic form with respect to $u, u_t, (u_t-\sigma u_{xx}+gu)$ and it can be shown that there exist values of $Q,a >0$ and $g \in \mathbb{R}$ that make $M$ positive definite. Thus for such values, $M$ is diagonalizable.

How can we use this to yield the desired inequality?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit strange that an inequality about $\dot W$ is given when an identity about $W$ is already given, and it seems that $u$ satisfies some PDE. Is there more context hidden?

Comment: @Saad Yes, the pde is $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx} + \sigma u_{txx} - \mu u_{t}, t>0, x \in (0,L)$ with $u_x(t,0) = u(t,L) = 0$. The given inequality somehow leads to $\dot{W}(t) \leq \varepsilon W(t)$ with the appropriate manipulation of the quadratic form, but I'm having trouble deriving it.

Comment: Another question: The line “where $σ,μ,a,L,c,Q$ are positive, $g\in\mathbb R$, $ω\in(0,1)$” suggests that these variables are given constants, but your attempt says that “there exist values of $Q,a>0$ and $g\in\mathbb R$ that make $M$ positive definite.” So are these variables fixed as given or up to one's own selection?

Comment: @Saad $g, Q$ and $a$ are up to one's own selection, but according to an indication, we shall select values that make $M$ positive definite. I've shown that there exist such values, but don't know how to use positive definiteness though.